# how to open popup "switch account" in the metamask with web3js (etherjs, web3-react)

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js, web3-react

In my application:
when user connect wrong account I have switch account button => Expected: click the button then open the account switch popup in the metamask.
Target bellow as image:

(I know it's crazy because can't interfere with the metamask but still want to try)

[image]